# Django form validation on create view only

Tags: python, django

I'm sure this is a simple one but Google isn't helping me today! 
I am trying to have the following validation run only at the Create view stage as at some point the system needs to allow duplicates but not when the user creates a new calculation.

### Code from forms.py

```
def clean_tag_number(self):
    tag_number = self.cleaned_data['tag_number']
    try:
        Calc.objects.get(tag_number = tag_number)
    except Calc.DoesNotExist:
        return tag_number
    raise forms.ValidationError("You already have a calculation based on that tag number, please choose another.")
```

I have tried using `request.path` in `forms.py` to check the current url as I have done in some of my templates but this obviously doesn't work in `forms.py`. Any pointers would be much appreciated.

Comment: Why not validate it at the view instead? That's where you want the exception, not in the form.

Comment: I did try that and managed to get it working to a degree however the error was returned in the traceback page, not the template as it would if done using forms.py.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use your existing method, but check first whether `self.instance` and `self.instance.pk` are not None.

Answer (score 0):

```
def clean_tag_number(self):
    tag_number = self.cleaned_data['tag_number']
    qs = self.Meta.model.objects.filter(tag_number=tag_number)
    if self.instance:
        qs = qs.exclude(pk=self.instance.id)
    if qs.count() > 0:
        raise forms.ValidationError('You already have a calculation based on that tag number, please choose another.')

    return tag_number
```

Comment: Hi, on further testing this still prevents the update view from saving.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the posts and elaborating on Daniels answer below I have the following working code.

```
def clean_tag_number(self):
    tag_number = self.cleaned_data['tag_number']
    if self.instance and self.instance.pk == None:
        try:
            Calc.objects.get(tag_number = tag_number)
        except Calc.DoesNotExist:
            return tag_number
        except Calc.MultipleObjectsReturned:
            raise forms.ValidationError("You already have a calculation based on that tag number, please choose another.")
        raise forms.ValidationError("You already have a calculation based on that tag number, please choose another.")
    else:
        return tag_number
```

This is the first time Ive written any validation so please feel free to point out any issues.